# ¿Se puede crear un registro cuando se hace un php artisan migrate?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, web

Compañeros la duda que me surge es:

Se puede crear un registro automáticamente cuando se crea la migración?

Es decir que cuando haga el `**php artisan migrate**` y se creen las migración dentro de una de las tablas se cree un registro.

Y si esto se puede, que es necesario hacer.

Comment: Sí se puede: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding

Comment: @Shaz puedes "formalizar" tu respuesta? :P

Comment: @ArieCwHat Realmente creo que no vale la pena una respuesta aquí, lel OP simplemente debería revisar la documentación. Te invito a que escribas la respuesta en ese caso :)

Comment: Una vez completada la migración se pueden crear registros ahí mismo, mi recomendación es: no lo hagas, usa los seeders. Es la forma en que se debe trabajar con el Framework, si empezamos a hacer cosas raras en lo que trae de base, no tendría sentido utilizarlo, no sólo nos provee de algunas cosas "prehechas", también tiene una metodología de trabajo que deberíamos respetar, por el mantenimiento futuro de nuestros desarrollos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las migraciones son para levantar la DB, si quieres crear registros debes utilizar los seeder de laravel,

intenta un ejemplo:

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder;
```

dentro del archivo UsersTableSeeder que se creó en el directorio database/seeds/

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {

       for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

           \DB::table('users')->insert(array(
               'name'     => "algunNombre",
               'email'    => "algunEmail",
               'password' => \Hash::make('secreto'),
           ));          
       }
   }
}
```

luego registras el seeder en /database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
}
```

luego ejecutas el siguiente comando en la terminal

```
composer dump-autoload
```

luego

```
php artisan db:seed
```

acá puedes revisar la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding